# How do I average a column of values filter by categories? In Power Bi

Tags: filter, powerbi

So I have a table that have a column with values and an other with the category "National" or "International".
I need to calculate the average percentage of the values in the national category! And only return the value in % so that i can see it on a card.
[Example of the data i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8FfZ.png)

[Need to see it in a visual like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoKyG.png)

```
National =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo]),
    'SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo] IN { "Nacional" }
)
```

```
%National =
DIVIDE(
    [National], 
    COUNTA('SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo])
)
```

Comment: Do yo uneed it in an extra column? Do you need it in a visual? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add your expected output.

Comment: I need it in a visual in a card so that you see the average value. I have done this 
National =CALCULATE(COUNTA('SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo]),'SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo] IN { "Nacional" })
%National =DIVIDE([National], COUNTA('SEGUIMIENTO'[Tipo]))
But i dont get the correct value

Comment: How your output is 96.80% from this sample data?  there are 3 row for Nacional and total  row 9. You are getting 33.33% which is correct result I guess.